# Laravel touching (recursive)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Question**: how to touch a model from the same model?

**Details:**
I'm using Laravel 5.4 to build an application for renting books between people.
In each transaction there are 2 parts: information concerning the owner VS information concerning the person who is renting the book.

Because the the 2 sides, I chose to use only one table named `rents` for both sides. To distinguish which is which I added a field `rent_side` that contains 'owner' or 'borrower'.
This makes it easy if I want to show/search a history of a person. If had 2 ore more tables, I would have to make a UNION to select all the data needed to show the history.

These two sides are coupled together thanks to common id called `couple_id`.

From each side, I can see the opposed side thanks to method located in the model `App\Rent` I named `reverse`, where I do the following:

```
public function reverse()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Rent', 'couple_id', 'couple_id')
        ->where('id', '!=', $this->id);
}
```

Because I need to update the parent timestaps and according to [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps) I used the following:

```
protected $touches = ['reverse'];
```

The problem is that this touching affects the same model. So when I update/insert a new record, the request takes up to 4min before sending an error. As if it went into an endless loop.

Is there a way to touch a model from the same model?

Comment: This indeed is an endless loop, a would touch b which would in turn touch a, I propose listening to eloquent events and updating the timestamp of the inverse when they are not equal.

Comment: @milo526 thank you for the advice. Let me try it..

Answer (score 0):

The source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ab05609a5aa291a6f91b38dbb2800e3ac80a4f97/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L433) does indeed show that it would result in an infinite loop.

What I suggest is you do the following:

```
class Rent extends Model {
      protected $touches = [ "reverse" ];

      protected function touchOwners() {
           static $recursionCount = 0;
           if ($recursionCount <= 1) {
              $recursionCount++:
              parent::touchOwners();
           } else {
             $recursionCount=0;
           }
      }
}
```

Haven't tested it so not 100% sure it would work.

Alternatively what would work would be:

Manually ensure you're touching the related model whenever you save a model

Comment: Unfortunately, overriding the touchOwners method with the suggested code didn't stop the infinite loop :\

Comment: if by 'manually touching the related model', you mean update the timestamps of the reversed side, it didn't help either since I'm using a package called [Plastic package](https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic) which works great with the $touches variable.